# :after is not working as expected - CSS

Tags: html, css

Below is the button I want

[image]

[**JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eme19uxg/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h5 style="margin: 0;position: relative;" class="right-arrow">LEARN MORE</h5>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.right-arrow:after {
    content: '';
    content: '';
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: white;
    border-width: 8px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

**Problem**

Don't know why right arrow is going outside ...

**Possible solution I don't want**

I don't want my `div` of fix width !! so `float: left;` in `div` is needed. Other solutions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: When arrow is positioned absolutely, you has to make a space for it using right padding on parent element.

Comment: Exactly, that's why you'd want to use `postition:relative` for your `::after`

Comment: `position: relative;` for `:after` won't solve the problem because it give other problems, you may check in jsfiddle by yourself !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
div {
background-color: red;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 0.5em 30px .5em .5em; /* added right padding */
float: left;
position: relative;
}

.right-arrow:after {
  content: '';
  content: '';
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: white;
  border-width: 8px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 8px; /* newly added */
}
```

You need to set padding right for the background div like this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eme19uxg/3/)**

Comment: Thanks ... I used `padding: 0.5em 2em .5em .5em;` !!

Answer (score 0):

make the following **css** changes

http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/x4knsgcj/

```
.right-arrow{padding:0 25px 0 0 }
.right-arrow:after {
content: '';
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: white;
  border-width: 8px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 10px;
  right: -27px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.right-arrow:after {
 content: '';
 vertical-align: middle;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 border-left-color: white;
 border-width: 8px 0 8px 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eme19uxg/4/)

```
div {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0.5em 1.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.right-arrow:after {
  /* content: ''; */
  content: '';
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  border-left-color: white;
  border-width: 8px 0 8px 16px;
  position: absolute;
  /* padding-left: 10px; */
  right: -20px;
  top: 0;
}
```